Rearrange data in table format to rows
Could anyone guide me on this data manipulation task? I have data like this in a spreadsheet:
(CSV)
Date,Slot 1,Slot 2,Slot 3
1/1/2024,AB,CD,EF
1/2/2024,AB
1/3/2024,CD,EF
...
I'd like it displayed as:
1/1/2024,AB
1/1/2024,CD
1/1/2024,EF
1/2/2024,AB
1/3/2024,CD
1/3/2024,EF
Sample spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12_5QORbukvGv_0LWQY8rDXoHa1hMGHYrzSg9Wv2LQ7E/edit?usp=sharing

Can you share a minimal, reproducible example that the community can use to see what you'd like to do? Like a dummy sheet so we can visualize and replicate what you have. Kindly include your desired output in it as well.

I'm guessing that this sample output is what you're looking for. However, it isn't specified if you'd like to use google-sheets-formula or google-apps-script for the answer, so it's best that you include that when you edit the question together with what you've done so far in attempting to resolve this concern.

@Saddles, yes that screenshot is exactly correct. I'll add to the question above.

You can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TOCOL(A2:A7&"❅"&B2:D7),"❅"),"where Col2<>''")) 


Upvoted +1, but would be better if open-ended ranges used with the date format in Column A such as; =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TOCOL(TEXT(A2:A,"mm/dd/yyyy")&"❅"&B2:D),"❅"),"where Col2<>''")) 

It seems that, you have changed your mind and instead of the sample data at the beginning of your first message (which looks like a CSV format as mentioned in your first sentence), now according to your sample sheet in your edited message, it looks like a regular data.
So, according to your sample sheet you can use the formula below;
=LET(Ø,BYROW(A2:D,LAMBDA(row, TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,row))),ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(Ø,","),,1),"mm/dd/yyyy")&"_"& SPLIT(MID(Ø, FIND(",",Ø)+1,LEN(Ø)), ",")), "_"), "Select Col1, Col2 Where Col2 Is Not Null"))))

.



Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=let(Σ,tocol(,1),reduce(Σ,A2:A10,lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserr(+a),Σ,a),let(Λ,tocol(offset(c,,1,,columns(B:D)),1),if(iserr(+Λ),Σ,{map(sequence(rows(Λ)),lambda(x,c)),Λ}))))))



You can try the below formula which is in cell C2;
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A,","),,1),"mm/dd/yyyy")&"_"& SPLIT(MID(A2:A, FIND(",",A2:A)+1,LEN(A2:A)), ",")), "_"), "Select Col1, Col2 Where Col2 Is Not Null"))),LAMBDA(row, JOIN(",",row)))

.

